# How to select only enabled fields using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
 $('#btnSelectAll').click(function() {
       $('.inputchbox').attr('checked', true);
 });

$('#btnCancel').click(function() {
     $('fieldset:not(:checked)').find("input,select,textarea").removeAttr('disabled');
 });
```

On cancel I need to enable only the checkboxes which are checked? Can I use something like this?

On selectall button I am selecting all the checkboxes from my fieldset
but here I need to select only the enabled checkboxes and the not disabled checkboxes.. 
So checkboxes are disabled on my fieldset on the load it self?

How to exclude disabled checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an intervening filter:

```
$('.inputchbox').filter(function() { return !this.disabled; }).attr('checked', true);
```

*edit* — or you can do like @sAc says and use a filter selector; I have a mental block about those so you probably shouldn't listen to me. It's probably something that happened in my childhood.

Comment: That seems to be way to go if that is what OP is looking for possibly, his question isn't that clear though.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `(':checkbox:enabled')` selector to select only ***enabled*** checkboxes.

More info on [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) and [`:enabled`](http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple attributes at once  i.e.

input:checkbox[name*='name']:checked:enabled

to check if name contains 'name' and checkbox is checked and also enabled, however you should get the length to check in boolean form i.e.

```
if ($("input:checkbox[name*='name']:checked:enabled").length) {
                    isValid = true;
                }
```